# parity check matrix for MRD Code

Tags: coding-theory

How to find parity check matric for an MRD code C $\subseteq$$(F_{q^N})^n$ of dimension k with the generator matrix G where $g_1, g_2,....g_n$ are elements of  $F_{q^N}$ and linearly independent over $F_{q}$; n is less than or equal to N and k is less than or equal to n

$$
G=
\pmatrix{ g_1 & g_2 & \dots & g_n \\ 
{g_1}^{q^{1}} & {g_2}^{q^{1}} & \dots & {g_n}^{q^{1}}\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\
{g_1}^{q^{k-1}} & {g_2}^{q^{k-1}} &  \cdots & {g_n}^{q^{k-1}}}
$$

Comment: What does _MRD_ mean?

Comment: Maximum Rank Distance